# Typescript interface value as enum or Record

Tags: typescript, types, enums

Suppose I have some object that could have either `key` as string and `value` as either `enum` or object with key and value as enum.

**types**

```
export enum ERRORS {
  ERROR1 = 'Error1',
  ERROR2 = 'Error2',
}

export type ErrorType = 'blue' | 'green';

export interface ErrorByCode {
  [key: string]: ERRORS | Record<ErrorType, ERRORS>;
}
```

**code**

```
const ERRORS_BY_CODE: ErrorByCode = {
  default: ERRORS.ERROR1,
  '01': ERRORS.ERROR2,

  '2': {
    blue: ERRORS.ERROR1,
    green: ERRORS.ERROR2,
  },
};

const errorResolver = ({code, type}: {code: string; type: ERRORS}) => {
    const errorMessage =
    (ERRORS_BY_CODE?.[code] || ERRORS_BY_CODE?.[code]?.[type]) ??
    ERRORS_COMPONENTS_BY_CODE.default;

    return errorMessage
};

console.log(errorResolver({code: '01', type: 'blue'}))
```

But I've got ts error under

> ***ERRORS_BY_CODE?.[code]?.[type]***
> *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'ErrorType' can't be used to index type 'ERRORS | Record<ErrorType,
> ERRORS>'.   Property 'blue' does not exist on type 'ERRORS_BY_CODE |
> Record<InsuranceType, ERROR_COMPONENTS>'.*

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wzy7Qm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing (e.g., no missing declarations like `code`, `type`, `ERRORS_COMPONENTS_BY_CODE`, and `InsuranceType`).  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not expect anyone to try to index into a `string` (which `ERRORS` is) with a key like `"blue"`, and it does not allow it.  It will consider that property to be of type `any`, and give a compile error:

```
function nope(str: string) {
    str.blue // error! Property 'blue' does not exist on type 'string'
}
```

If a value is of a type which is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `string` and something else, the compiler will also be unhappy about such an indexing, since it might be a `string` for all it knows:

```
function stillNope(uni: string | { blue: number }) {
    uni.blue // error! Property 'blue' does not exist on type 'string'
}
```

[Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) does not fix this.  You are not allowed to access an unknown property on an object even if you use `?.` instead of `.`.  This prohibition is intentional; see [microsoft/TypeScript#33736](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33736) for more information.

---

If you want to access a property on a union type where at least one of the members of the union is not known to have that property, you will need to use some other form of type guarding.  One way is to use [`typeof` guarding](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards):

```
function typeofGuard(
  uni: ERRORS | { blue: ERRORS, green: ERRORS }, 
  type: ErrorType
) {
    const errors = typeof uni === "string" ? uni : uni[type];
}
```

---

The other possibility is to represent your union as one where each member of the union has known behavior at the `ErrorType` keys.  Instead of `ERRORS`, which is a `string` with no known behavior at `ErrorType`, you can make it `ERRORS & {[P in ErrorType]?: undefined }`.  Meaning: it is `ERRORS`, and if you index into it with an `ErrorType` key, you will get an `undefined` property.  This makes your error go away also:

```
function exclusiveUnion(
    uni: (ERRORS & { [P in ErrorType]?: undefined }) | (Record<ErrorType, ERRORS>),
    type: ErrorType
) {
    const errors = uni[type]; // ERRORS | undefined
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKICUsHksDKcA3gFBwWY74CMcAvHAOQZRTQ1MA05l2eWAEwNmrdlEHdSAX1KlQkWHBgBPMMExtoAFTUbGTAEYAbZMCZwAPswDmUYEiYBuOQDNkiAMYwAlhERwiBDqABQAzjBQAFxwEVA+iDYAlCS8FHEAdCZmcAD0uQhaUACEcAAK7OqwKszZ5nAAJhDAYYEQ8KA+EXD+ynrMcQk2TDJuHt5+ARE+xsYAcsHAIR4+MYOJViRwdTEoqIbAUHDSKWSUcCtZphr5heKlFYvVtdcWTS1tHSBd8L2q6gNIkNnGkLogfAB+K45W6He6jUjuLy+P56CCuADiyAAhlAGstwTF+PgiNZiNtrkTqIQuHA7A5EFSBERpLT-sAiUVdOpTqDPP5unDoK1GOz0WCfAx6IwAETrGwyuAQiVwGIrADa7IAui5ZIjxiiAqBPKYwj4AG7AACq4P8IVBKxiIWJhDgADItuqynAEppxNzgFqIWrEA1gK4EsAGscUtYQlhgPy8QAeMQ6PS0l0EAB8SR453ZnP9elIvPO-MQgqKIolmr0OryBSzmw8YYjiCjCPk4Gg8ASMEOrmxng0aagACEVABhCBh1LndUAa2AKjWQMSWqdoPOzY95K9PoCY4DQZDbcj0dk51jcHt53OCaTDVTXIzVGZ2dBSV1clIFe6WYAPrjgAmoBU64AAIhgRbQJOM5zowZyUG22LIMYMBMiSGQujQPCgkwAAMnBYYQOHUoI+HnEwkgxMh94UmYpEEORAh4dulD0kgzGsfglGgqyMguKQYYmriGj-vA-Jhmu8SJC4onGOJcCSX06iwVAAYKYmSn2CpArwEBEEALJlLgcwYHM2gEMBYEQdBdGNOGaEYcxxx-gZCAiEBoHgVBGDqtJgZ1uoDa3M21ituGF6-kAA)